# Best name for link table

Tags: database-design, naming-convention

I was wondering what the best name for a linked table in this situation (or any) would be. I've searched for this, but could not find any concrete examples.

For example, I have the following tables (where 'table in the name refers to tables in a restaurant):

- restaurant_table
- restaurant_table_feature

A table can have all kind of features and also multiple. Think of rounded tables, tables near the window, ground-floor tables, tables near entrance. It really depends on the type of restaurant, so it needs to be customizable. Arrangements are not permanent, since tables can be moved around for various reasons. Usually, the smallest possible combination of a table has a table number, if tables are combined for a group, multiple table numbers are used.

I want to link multiple features to a table row, with a linked table. Should I call the linking table *restaurant_table_feature_table* or *restaurant_table_to_feature*.

I've seen both possibilities in multiple systems, but which one would be the preferred one?

I also could simply rename *restaurant_table_feature* to *restaurant_feature*, and create a *restaurant_table_feature* table as link table. However if I also have a *restaurant_location* table for which I would have features (which differ from the table features) I would run into problems.

*To be clear, my question is what the best name would be (for the many-to-many tables) in any situation with multiple many-to-many tables.*

Comment: `FooBar` is the name I would normally use. However, if I would also have a `World` table, and this could also have `Bar`'s, but different 'bars' as the `Foo` table, with different columns. Then the `Bar` tables would become, `FooBar` and `WorldBar`. The linking tables would become `FooBarFoo` or `FooFooBar` and `WorldBarWorld` or `WorldWorldBar`, and this seems a little strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally developer's choice but in my opinion `restaurant_tables` implies `one-to-many` relationship. When a table resolves `many-to-many` relationship I prefer names like `restaurants_X_dishes`. Again, this is up to my taste.

Comment: So `restaurant_table_X_feature` in this example then?

Comment: If features belong to table level, not restaurant as a whole

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm marking this as accepted answer, as it seems to be most clear one. However I still would prefer to use `_to_` instead of `_X_`, I think it would be better readable in a MVC/ORM environment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess link table expresses some relationship, for example current feature to table availability or plans to deploy feature or history or all of them (requires more attributes besides just FKs). So it may be `availability#restaurant_table_feature#restaurant_table` for the first case or `status#restaurant_table_feature#restaurant_table` for the last one.

Comment: Yes, but my question is just about how to name the link-table, in any many-to-many situation

Comment: I believe name should someway reflect the content this table intended for. If it's _any_ content at all, then just `m2m#restaurant_table_feature#restaurant_table`

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest restaurant_table_continued